# Using multiple ssh keys with different GitHub accounts

Tags: git, github, ssh

This is my `ssh-config` -

```
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_gortnm // vansham-gortnm
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github // vanshamagg
```

And I am using the command `ssh -N github.com` to check which account connects to.

I get the response something like -

`Hi vanshamagg! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access. Connection to github.com closed.`

When I specify only one Identity it connects to the right account. But whenever I add both Identities, it always connects to `vanshamagg` no matter in what order I specify the keys.

Any ideas why it might be happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+%5Bssh%5D+multiple+accounts

Comment: As for your question exactly: `ssh` always uses the first key found in `.ssh/config`. So put specific options at the beginning and more generic options at the end of the file.